# Association rule mining for multiple cuts of the same datasource

Tags: r, lapply, apriori, arules

Goal: Produce a list of the top 5 association rules (by confidence) per Department per report.

My existing syntax and test data:

```
# Create fake data; 1= used report, 0 = didn't use report
data <- data.frame(Dept=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'), 
              Rep1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1), 
              Rep2=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), 
              Rep3=c(1,1,1,0,0,0),
              Rep4=c(0,1,0,1,1,0),
              Rep5=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
              Rep6=c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
              Rep7=c(1,1,1,1,1,0),
              Rep8=c(0,0,0,1,1,0),
              Rep9=c(1,0,0,1,1,0),
              Rep10=c(1,1,0,0,1,1)
              )

# Turn all variables to factors
data<-data.frame(lapply(data, factor))

# Changes 0s to NAs, only interested in rules where the report was used
data[data==0]<-NA

# lapply command to run apriori on the data when split by Dept
rules <- lapply(split(data, list(data$Dept)), function(x) {
  # Turn split data into transactions
  temp <- as(x[ , 2:length(x)], "transactions")
  # Create rules; artificially low parameters for testing
  temp <- apriori(temp, parameter = list(support=0.01, confidence=0.1,  minlen=2, maxlen=2))
  # Order rules by confidence, eventually will select top 5 (I'm able to do that), and change it to a data frame for later use
  temp <- as(sort(temp, by = "confidence")[0:length(temp)], "data.frame")
})  

# Breaks out the results into separate data.frames
list2env(rules,.GlobalEnv)
```

This results in ~50 rules per Department.  However, they are at the global level of Department. For example, the Dept A data.frame has...

```
rules                support   confidence  lift
{Rep9=1}=>{Rep6=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5
{Rep4=1}=>{Rep6=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5
...
```

Ideally, my data.frames should look along the lines of...

*Dept. A with Report 9 only data.frame*

```
rules                support   confidence  lift
{Rep9=1}=>{Rep6=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5
{Rep9=1}=>{Rep10=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5    
...
```

*Dept. A with Report 4 only data.frame*

```
rules                support   confidence  lift
{Rep4=1}=>{Rep6=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5
{Rep4=1}=>{Rep10=1}  .3333333   1.00000000  1.5    
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at rule templates to restrict the left-hand-side (LHS) of the rules to a certain department. Have a look at the examples in `? APappearance` in arules.

The code to restricts the LHS to a department will look somewhat like this:

`rules_Rep9 <- apriori(temp, 
       parameter = list(support=0.01, confidence = 0.1), 
       appearance = list(lhs = c("Rep9=1"), default="rhs"))`

Comment: I was thinking of using subset and it does provide the additional break I want.  Ideally though, I would like the syntax to produce all possible breaks as opposed to running through it one at a time (IRL, there are a lot more departments and reports).  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can easily run the code above or use subset inside a for loop like `for (dept in c("A", "B", etc.)) { select subset and mine rules }`.